# Java stack overflow error - Graph algorithm

Tags: java, graph, hashmap, stack-overflow

I am using as a data structure for represent a graph,a HashMap - HashMap (one for the locality and one inside the locality in order to represent the destinations) , i had inserted 20 000 localities.
Now i need to make a function to know if exist a path between two Localities, this function is recursive and it require me to make a lot of get objects of my hashMap to work with them.
For each destination to make i have always to execute the method get in my api, to give me a copy of the hashMap with the destinations
Everytime that i run my program, i get a Stackoverflow error. Why this always happen ? it's due the high recursive calls? Or it 's due the constantly call get method to have a copy of the hashMap of the locality's destinations?

thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code? That would make diagnosing the problem easier.

Comment: Whoops removed the stackoverflow tag thinking you meant the website :) as @HunterMcMillen said though we will be able to help a lot more with code posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack overflows are caused by the recursion depth exceeding some fixed limit.  This probably has nothing to do with copying the `HashMap`; that would cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.  If you are doing a graph search recursively, the error is likely caused by either

1. A depth-first search going too deep, or
2. A bug in your recursion logic.

Without more data I can't say which it is.  Do note, though, that DFS can be written iteratively using an explicit stack to store the nodes to explore.  Posting more code would help us make a better diagnosis.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's the recursive calls. Each level of recursive call consumes space on the stack, so if you are getting a large number of these calls you will run out of stack space. Change your algorithm to be non-recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help, the problem is already solved. I decided to forget the recursive calls, and choice the DFS variant .

Answer (score 0):

Which algorithm do you use for finding the shortest path? Can it contain circles or negative edge weights?
Depending on that, use Dijktra, Prim, Floyd-Warshall or whatsoever. Steven Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual", p. 206ff gives some good detailed explanations on various shortest path graph algorithms. I'm sure, many of them are iterative rather than recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing happen for a smaller graph?
If so , you have some bug in your recursion that probably causes an infinite recursion.
If doesn't happen for smaller graphs, this is your algorithm that knocks you down.